# Is it a problem if a bookcase isn’t fully touching the floor?

Tags: walls, screws

IKEA assemblers have screwed a large bookcase (180cm height x 160cm width x 40cm depth) into my wall where the top is 10mm from the wall and the base is 17mm from from wall, meaning the bookcase doesn’t sit squarely on the floor and the outer edge is lifted by around 3-4mm. Should I be worried? Should I be worried the screws in the wall or the bookcase gets damaged?

Comment: I'm confused.  If the top is 10mm from the wall and the bottom is 17mm away, that means there is a large gap between the bookcase and the wall.  So how can it be screwed to the wall?  And since the gaps are different, is it the wall or the bookcase that is leaning away from vertical?

Comment: The wall is 90 degrees. There’s a long-enough metal bracket that connects the bookcase to the wall but where the bracket connects to the wall that part doesn’t sit flush with the bookcase, it sticks out a little. At the top, it should have stuck out 17mm, but the assemblers have screwed the top brackets deeper and now the bookcase has a very slight backward lean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quite commonly install shims to support the front of (brand-agnostic) bookcases so they are leaning towards the wall, not away from it. Should be trivial to get a pack of shims  (thin wooden wedges - narrow wooden shingles) and properly support the front of this bookcase as installed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the bookcase is sitting on the floor but the front edge of the bottom is a little lifted?  I would not be worried.  If you are worried chuck a few shims under it.  Each screw is probably rated in excess of 50lbs of pull out, even if the bookcase somehow pulled forward you could just add some washer to the screws and re-secure it.

Screwing to the wall prevents the bookcase from falling forward on you - most people don't bother securing bookcases to the walls.  Small children have died from small dressers falling on them for that reason and ikea has recalled some due to the forward center of gravity which if not secured to walls makes it quite easy for them to fall forward if the drawers are opened and loaded.  Other than the tip forward there isn't much point to being secured to the wall.

The only time I'd be worried was if aesthetically the book case looked like it was tipped forward but given the minimal difference on the front edge I suspect that is not the case. Also most of the weight on a bookcase is likely to be loaded to the back of the bookcase.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to depend on the construction of the shelf and load capacity of the mounting brackets, but I don't like your chances. It sounds like the installer did a poor job, and I would have it re-installed if I were in your shoes.